# How to get to objects nested in a jsonb array?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I've been trying to refer to a column in the function `jsonb_to_recordset()` instead of entering it in the raw form. The table structure we are talking about is this:

```
CREATE TABLE clusters (
cluster_id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
cluster_name text,
cluster_restrictors jsonb);
```

A single `cluster_restrictor` looks like this:

```json
{
  "min_av_grade": null, 
  "min_tot_grade": null, 
  "restrictor_reqs": [{"grade": "2:1","restriction": ["Physics"]}],
  "restrictor_type": "BSc"
}
```

My latest attempt to retrieve a table-like result is:

```
WITH arrb AS (
  SELECT jsonb_agg(cluster_restrictors) 
from clusters
) 
SELECT jsonb_to_recordset(jsonb_agg) AS (restrictor_type text) 
FROM arrb;
```

ending in a syntax error.

So shortly, how to get from this?

```
 cluster_id | cluster_name |                                                                          cluster_restrictors
------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          3 |              | [{"min_av_grade": null, "min_tot_grade": null, "restrictor_reqs": [{"grade": "2:1", "restriction": ["Physics"]}], "restrictor_type": "BSc"}]
          4 |              | [{"min_av_grade": null, "min_tot_grade": null, "restrictor_reqs": [{"grade": "2:1", "restriction": 7}, {"grade": "2:2", "restriction": 8}], "restrictor_type": "BSc"}]
```

to this:

```
 restrictor_type |                             restrictor_reqs
-----------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 BSc             | [{"grade": "2:1", "restriction": 7}, {"grade": "2:2", "restriction": 8}]
 BSc             | [{"grade": "2:1", "restriction": ["Physics"]}]
```

What could be done?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output is supposed to look like please

Comment: I read your question several times and still don't know what you are asking exactly. Please clarify.

Comment: What is `restrictor_type`? What are you trying to select? Why are you doing `jsonb_agg(cluster_restrictors)` instead of referring to `clusters.cluster_restrictors` in your actual query?

Comment: Clarifications made. Thank you for the engagement

Comment: I suggest the new title as edited as the old one seemed focused on the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can just use (the simpler) [**`jsonb_array_elements()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) instead of `jsonb_to_recordset()` and then plain field extraction operators:

```sql
SELECT cr.value ->> 'restrictor_type' AS restrictor_type
     , cr.value ->  'restrictor_reqs' AS restrictor_reqs
FROM   clusters c, jsonb_array_elements(c.cluster_restrictors) cr;
```

See:

- [How to turn JSON array into Postgres array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684)